# Cannot migrate postgres db between 2 servers ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to migrate data from old server to new server, both of them used ubuntu server. 
I have used this command:

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```

but it throw:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "X.X.X.X" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have checked postgresql conf on new server, running on 5432, listen..="*"
Anything wrong?
Thanks all !

Comment: the error is fairly obvious. The server is dropping connections on that port. Which can happen for a multitude of reasons such as firewalls, not listening on the public IP etc etc

Comment: I have run "ufw status" and it show "inactive".
"not listening on the public IP", what do you mean? Can you explain and what should I do to check?